# How to iterate through an enumeration of flags and create checkboxes that are checked appropriately for each value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, enums, flags

I have an `Enum` of flags to represent the days of the week, with a few extra values that indicate weekdays, weekends, every day, or no days.

Here's the `Enum`:

```
[Flags]
public enum DayOfWeek : short
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64,
    Weekday = 62,
    Weekend = 65,
    Everyday = 127,
    None = 0
}
```

I also have a View Model with a property, `DayOfWeek` with a type of `DayOfWeek`.

In my View, I need to create a checkbox for each day of the week and somehow appropriately check the boxes based on which days have been saved.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a good solution.

Here's what I came up with:

```
@foreach (DayOfWeek item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
{
    if (0 < item && (item <= DayOfWeek.Friday || item == DayOfWeek.Saturday))
    {
        @Html.Label("DayOfWeek", item.ToString())
        @Html.CheckBox("DayOfWeek", (Model.DayOfWeek.HasFlag(item)), new { value = item })
    }
}
```

The conditional statement within the loop is to ensure that only the actual days get displayed.

This works for my purposes, and the concept can be easily applied to other Enumerations. Specific implementation will need some changes, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your `Enum` like this:

```
foreach (var val in typeof(DayOfWeek).GetEnumNames())
               ....
```

Also you can `Pars` and convert back a `string` to your `Enum`

```
var day = Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek) , yourString);
```

`yourstring` can be anything you want for example the name of the `checkbox`.

I don't know more about your problem and your project architecture, it's up to you to adapt these options to your problem.I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

It's a fairly manual process... To check if Sunday is selected, for example:

```
bool isSunday = (dayOfWeekEnum & DayOfWeek.Sunday) == DayOfWeek.Sunday;
```